# binary heap - how and when to use max-heapify

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, max-heap

i'm reading about the heap data structure, and i can't figure out when to use max heapify function and why.

I wrote a insert function that will always keep the heap a max-heap and i can't see when will max-heapify ever be used.

Can you please explain?
Thank you

this is my code:

```cpp
  int  PARENT(int i) {
    return i/2;
  }

  int LEFT(int i) {
    return 2*i;
  }
  
  int RIGHT(int i ) {
    return 2*i +1;
  }

  void max_heapify(int *v, int index, int heapsize) {
    int largest;
    int left = LEFT(index);
    int right = RIGHT(index);
  
    if (left<heapsize && v[left] > v[index])
      largest = left;
    else 
      largest = index;
  
    if (right < heapsize && v[right] > v[largest])
      largest = right;
  
    if (largest !=index) {
      v[index]  = v[index] ^v[largest];
      v[largest] = v[index] ^v[largest];
      v[index] = v[index] ^v[largest];
      max_heapify(v,largest,heapsize);
    }
  }

  void insert(int *v, int * length, int value) {
    v[++*length] = value;
    int valuePos = *length;
    int parent = PARENT(valuePos);

    if (parent!=valuePos) {
      while (v[parent] < v[valuePos]) {
        v[parent] = v[parent] ^ v[valuePos];
        v[valuePos] = v[parent] ^v[valuePos];
        v[parent] = v[parent] ^ v[valuePos];
        valuePos = parent;
        parent = PARENT(valuePos);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note: The standard library already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The heapify algorithm should be used when turning an array into a heap. You could do that by inserting each array element in turn into a new heap, but that would take O(*n* lg *n*) time, while heapify does it in O(*n*) time.

Comment: so then, there's something wrong with my max_heapify algorithm as i tried to call the function for an unordered array to turn it into a heap. It doesn't work though. Can you please give me an  example? I've tried calling max_heapify(v,0,n) but the result isn't a heap

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, may_heapify() will only work on sorted sequences. Since inserting elements in a heap is, in a way, sorting them, insertion MUST take at least O(_n_ lg _n_) time - there is no faster sorting algorithm :) But, you can use the function to turn a sorted sequence in a heap in O(_n_), while inserting _n_ elements with an `insert` function will _always_ take O(_n_ lg _n_) no matter what order they are in.

Answer (score 0):

`max_heapify` is expected to invoke on a regular array, to make it a heap. And `insert` does the maintenance work, which requires the array (`v` in your function) already being a heap.

Answer (score 0):

The `max-heapify` function, as you call it, is a general `heapify` function (a heap can use any valid comparison function for sorting it's elements). It is intended to be used as an `init` function for constructing a heap from an array.

The complexities of functions for dealing with a heap (with their intented usages):

- `init` (*max-heapify*): O(*n*) , used to initialize a heap from a **sorted** sequence (array) (max-sorted, in your case)
- `insert` : O(lg *n*) , used to insert a single element in a heap (maintains the heap tree "sorted")
- `delete` : O(lg *n*) , used to remove a "best" (max, in your case) element from a heap (maintains the heap tree "sorted")

But, since this question is tagged `C++`, you should also consider using a [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) from `STL` instead of implementing your own heap. Complexities of the considered operations are the same as for any heap implementation, and it can easily operate with any comparison function (either pre-written or user-written). Another advantage against a heap implementation is that it is a sorted container, and you can easily iterate trough all the elements in the sorted order (not just the first one) without destroying the structure.

The only problem with `std::set` is that it is a unique container - meaning, only 1 copy of an element with a same key can exist in it. But there is a solution for that also - `std::multiset` keeps sorted instances of multiple objects with the same key.

Also, depending on your required usage (it there is a lot of data associated with the search key), you might also want to try `std::map` or `std::multimap`.

If you want to make your own heap implementation, I would strongly suggest putting it in a separate class (or even a namespace) if your intention is to use `C++` to the fullest. If you just intend to keep the implementation in the form it is, you should consider re-tagging the question to `C`

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the data in heap randomly like in array. Afterwards u can call the max heapify function to keep the property of a Max Heap. Here is my code

```
class max_heap{  
 private:               // are the private members of class
      int *arr;
      int size;
      int ind;
};

        void max_heap::bubbledown(int *ar, int i)
        {
         int len = ind - 1;
         int lt = 2 * i;
         int rt = lt + 1;
         while (lt <= len && rt <= len)                                         
         {
            if (arr[i] > arr[lt] && arr[i] > arr[rt])
                break;

            else if (ar[lt] > ar[rt])
            {
                if (ar[i] < ar[lt]){
                    swap(ar[i], ar[lt]);
                    i = lt;
                    lt = 2 * i;
                }
            }
            else if (ar[lt] < ar[rt])
            {
                if (ar[i] < ar[rt]){
                    swap(ar[i], ar[rt]);
                    i = rt;
                    rt = (2 * i)+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void max_heap::heapify()
    {
        int len = ind - 1;
        for (int i = len; i >= 1 && (i/2) >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i/2])
            {
                swap(arr[i], arr[i/2]);
                bubbledown(arr, i);
            }
        }
    }
```